# How do I obtain a list of values from a website dropdown using selenium?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, dropdown

I am trying to get the names of all State from a respective dropdown named `State`.

However, the problem is, the list that I'm trying to generate doesn't return the names in the dropdown instead I'm getting a list of blank values. It does get the number of elements in the dropdown right, but the elements' values are blank.

What am I doing wrong? and how can I modify my code to get the desired result?

I am currently using selenium and the following is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = "https://vahan.parivahan.gov.in/vahan4dashboard/vahan/view/reportview.xhtml"
driver.get(url)
dropdown_element = driver.find_element(By.ID,"j_idt31_input")
dropdown = Select(dropdown_element)
option_names = [option.text for option in dropdown.options]
print(len(option_names))
print(option_names)
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you need to change is that you should use the method `.get_attribute('innerHTML')` instead of `.text` in order to get the text from the `option` tags under the `Select`.

Here's the complete solution:

```py
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions as EC

driver = Chrome()
url = "https://vahan.parivahan.gov.in/vahan4dashboard/vahan/view/reportview.xhtml"
driver.get(url)
dropdown_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "j_idt31_input")))
dropdown = Select(dropdown_element)
option_names = [option.get_attribute('innerHTML') for option in dropdown.options]
print(len(option_names))
print(option_names)
```

output:

```
35
['All Vahan4 Running States (34/36)', 'Andaman &amp; Nicobar Island(8)', 'Andhra Pradesh(80)', 'Arunachal Pradesh(26)', 'Assam(36)', 'Bihar(49)', 'Chhattisgarh(30)', 'Chandigarh(1)', 'UT of DNH and DD(3)', 'Delhi(23)', 'Goa(13)', 'Gujarat(37)', 'Himachal Pradesh(113)', 'Haryana(179)', 'Jharkhand(30)', 'Jammu and Kashmir(21)', 'Karnataka(68)', 'Kerala(87)', 'Ladakh(3)', 'Maharashtra(53)', 'Meghalaya(13)', 'Manipur(12)', 'Madhya Pradesh(52)', 'Mizoram(10)', 'Nagaland(9)', 'Odisha(39)', 'Punjab(93)', 'Puducherry(8)', 'Rajasthan(142)', 'Sikkim(8)', 'Tamil Nadu(146)', 'Tripura(9)', 'Uttarakhand(21)', 'Uttar Pradesh(78)', 'West Bengal(56)']
```